# More Efficient LINQ JOIN

Tags: linq, join

I am trying to join 2 tables with a one to may relationship but I only want "the one" column data to appear in one row, it should be null in all all other rows (don't care which ones). So:

```
TEACHER
---------
TeacherID
TeacherBiography
.
.
.

STUDENT
-----------
TeacherID
StudentFName
StudentLName
.
.
.
```

Example: You want to get all the students who's First Name is 'Joe', join the Teacher using TeacherID, but limit the returned results so that the Teacher data is not returned in every row. The reason is because the TeacherBiography is large; I need it returned, but not in every row.

So some sample output should look like:

```
------------------------------------------------
StudentFName | StudentLName | TeacherID | TeacherBiography
------------------------------------------------
'Joe'        | 'Smith'      | 1         | 'long biography for teacher 1..'  
'Joe'        | 'Jones'      | 2         | 'long biography for teacher 2..'  
'Joe'        | 'Michaels'   | 1         | null
'Joe'        | 'Rogers'     | 3         | 'long biography for teacher 3..' 
'Joe'        | 'Washington' | 1         | null
.
.
.
.
```

So in the case of Michaels and Washington the TeacherBiograph (and all other teacher columns) is null because the data was already returned in the Smith row.

How do I do it?

-J

Comment: Sorry, more efficient than sending the exact same long biography column many times in the result from the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only efficient way to do this is to Join `STUDENT`s and `TEACHER`s with the `TeacherID` as a key, then you can output this key only one time for only one row and the other rows for the same key output `null` instead, like this:

```
var StudentsList = students.Join(  //Inner join
    Teachers,
    s => s.TeacherID,
    t => t.TeacherID,
    (teacher, teacherStudetns) => 
        new
        {
            Teacher = teacher,
            HisStudents = teacherStudetns
        });
```

Then you can output only the key once, for example:

```
foreach(var item in StudentsList)
{
     Console.Writline("Teach Name: {0}, His students:", item.TeacherBiography);
     foreach(var student in item.HisStudents)
     {
         Console.writeLine("---------- {0}", student.StudentName);
     }
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this is just doing a JOIN and is still sending large amounts of duplicate teacher back from the DB. I'm not trying to print the results efficiently, I'm trying to get the results from the DB efficiently.

Comment: @user1346563, this is not fetching large amounts of duplicate teachers from the DB, it will be in the form *teacher -> list of students*, i. e.: each teach has a list of students, and if you are using LINQ to sql, your query will be executed in the database side and you won't be warried about effeciey. If you want to make your query to get a list of data in the form you posted in your question,  then you can compose your list manually be iterating each student fetch his's corresponding teacher only for the first one add `null` for the rest. and this will make your query totally inefficient.

Comment: Regardless of the nice relational object structure (teacher->students) we have in the our mind, in the DB and in the query, the DB is going to send a bunch of "flattened" rows back to the client, not teacher objects pointing to student objects (at least I think it will). So when it flattens them on the DB side to send back to the client, will it duplicate the teacher columns in each row where the TeacherID is the same? When I look at the query results in the debugger, it looks like the data is duplicated but that could be the client side of the DB driver "being smart".

Comment: @user1346563, There is now way to do this using one query, and the `join` is the only way to do this and it is the most effient way. Any way, if you want to do this you have to do it manually as I said, for each row you have to check for duplicate grouped teachers and replace them with null, this check will reduce your query efficeincy.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in two steps rather than complicating your code to try to get it done in one. First, retrieve the student information that you care about. Once you have that, you can perform another query to get the teacher information, given the distinct list of TeacherIDs.

```
var students = //student query
var teacherIds = students.Select(p => p.TeacherID).Distinct();
var teachers = teacherTable.Where(p => p.Contains(teacherIds));
```

You can then join the two results in memory.

```
var allData = from s in students
    join t in teachers on
    t.teacherID equals s.TeacherID
    select new { StudentName = s.Name, TeacherBio = t.TeacherBiography};
```

This will result in two database hits, but you will only return the data items you need.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about doing this, but it seems like such a common problem (every one-to-many join suffers from this issue to some extent) that there must be a simple, single query solution?